# AS3 Embedded Fonts list and their names

Tags: actionscript-3, embedded-fonts

How to get a list of all embedded fonts with their names using AS3.

Answer (score 13):

Use [`Font.enumerateFonts()`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/text/Font.html#enumerateFonts()).

```
var fonts:Array = Font.enumerateFonts();
for each(var font:Font in fonts)
    trace( font.fontName+":"+font.fontType );
```

Comment: Make note that this will only get you embedded fonts. If you want to grab all fonts on the user's machine then use `Font.enumerateFonts(false);` - I'm not telling you anything the documentation won't tell you, so have at it!

Comment: Thanks for the up vote, and I really don't want to be overly pedantic, but OP was specifically asking for a *list of embedded fonts*... ;)

Comment: Oh certainly, and you nailed the Q. I was merely adding some extra low-hanging-fruit info for anyone who may stroll past the comment in the future.

Comment: @Jackson - if you want to grab all fonts on the user's machine then use `Font.enumerateFonts(true);` not false (false is the default BTW).